# Why does the third dimension seem so elusive?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, partial-differential-equations

As a curios and deeply passionate *prospective* undergraduate doing some pre-study for fun and also in preparation for my future endeavours, i just stumbled upon a trend that fascinated me:

The proof of Fermat's Last Theorem for fourth exponents is arguably much easier than that for the third exponent (dimension). The Poincare conjecture for $\dim \geq 4$ was settled by Stephen Smale way before the heralded proof for $\dim 3$ by Grigori Perelman.

In algebraic geometry, most genus $1$ (degree $3$) curves continue to confound algebraic geometers to this day, for example, the Diophantine equation $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 =3$. The Navier-Stokes partial differential equations for dimension $3$ are still hardly understood.

So my question is, what's so special/elusive about the third dimension ? And is it possible to find an all encompassing ''unified theory'' that can possibly explain *all* the mathematics of $3$ dimensions from algebraic geometry, number theory and pde's (Navier-Stokes) ?

NOTE: I'm note too sure if the tags are appropriate. If not, please feel free to edit and insert the appropriate one(s). Thank you.

Comment: Actually, it tends to be dimension $4$ which is the most problematic. There's a rather famous quote by R.H. Bing: “Dimension 4 is the most diﬃcult dimension. It is too old to spank, the way we might deal with the little dimensions 1, 2, and 3; but it is also too young to reason with, the way we deal with the grown-up dimensions 5 and higher.”

Comment: The Poincaré conjecture for dimensions at least *five* was solved by Smale and a number of other authors. But topologically, four was solved by Freedman two decades later, and is open smoothly.

Comment: A rough answer would be that higher dimensions have more "degree of freedom“ to do things that are not possible in lower dimensions. Too low dimension like dimension 1,2 are trivial. So it appears that dimension 3,4 are the hardest. There are some exceptions: in calculating homotopy of spheres, I believe that high dimensions are harder..

Comment: The [four color theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem) comes here to mind.

Comment: @Lucian: Why and how does that come to mind, precisely?

Comment: @MikeMiller: Because the lower limit was reduced to five colors long before it was proven that only four are actually necessary.

Comment: "And is it possible..." No. In particular, there definitely cannot even be any general algorithmic solution to PDE in 3 dimensions. This impossibility result is actually provable, and the argument is remarkably simple: see [Remark 16](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/11/05/the-no-self-defeating-object-argument/).